# why my code in visual studio does not appear in my local host website?

Tags: wordpress, themes

I am trying to make a custom theme in WordPress.
after activation the new custom theme, I noticed that any changes that I made in visual studio is not reflected on the website which is running in the localhost,

also there are photos and script in website which does not relate to my current theme : starting theme, but to default theme

- I tried to refresh, delete the other themes, install gulp watch at terminal but failed

Comment: Did you try disabling the browser cache as step 1 in the debug process? https://www.webinstinct.com/faq/how-to-disable-browser-cache

Comment: yes i removed all cache

Comment: Impossible for me to help you. Could you be more clear? What do you mean by “ photos and script in website which does not relate to my current theme : starting theme, but to default theme”? Is it a child theme? If so, why didn’t you mention that in your question?